# Share data between multiple apps

Tags: android, database, sqlite, local-storage

I have multiple apps that have some sort of in-app currency (i.e gold).

The gold (Integer value) should be accessable through all of my apps. All of my own apps should be able to read/write the value.

It is important that only my apps are able to **write** the value, it doesn't matter if anyone else can read it.
It's also important that I do not know which of my apps is installed. There is no 'main'-app at all. It should be irrelevant which of my apps is installed and in which order.

The value does not have to be shared between the apps during runtime, I rather thought of something like sharedPreferences or an SQL database.

Where/How should I store this value?
Which is the preferred solution to this problem (if there is any)?

Comment: I think content providers, at least for the 'anyone else can read'

Comment: I think if I want to use the content provider I need some sort of 'main'-app that provides the content provider, and that's what I unfortunately don't have.

Comment: Then I do not know. Maybe with web services? The users create an account for your apps and it is the server who manages the exange of gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to share data between two (or more) apps, you can set to them the same `android:sharedUserId` (in `AndroidManifest.xml`) so the other app can read/write in the private data of the other app.

> android:sharedUserId
>
> The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared
>   with other applications. By default, Android assigns each application
>   its own unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same
>   value for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID —
>   provided that they are also signed by the **same certificate**.
>   **Application with the same user ID can access each other's data** and, if
>   desired, run in the same process.

Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html).

Comment: Looks like this  is now deprecated 